# Change the color of the Grid Cell in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview, componentone

I know how to do this on a standard `DataGridView`, for example:
`DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;` . How to do the same on `C1TrueDBGrid` (or `TrueDBGrid`) from ComponentOne library? (without using events). I tried many ways, including

```cs
DetailTGrid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
DetailTGrid[i, j].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
DetailTGrid.Columns[j].Rows[i].Style.ForeColor = Red;
```

But nothing works. edit: Well, or at least how to change the color of the entire line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who responded. Solved the problem and had to use event.

Used the **FetchCellStyle** event.

**FetchCellStyle** - Occurs whenever a cell is to be rendered and the C1DisplayColumn.FetchStyle is true.

Here is the code:

```
private void DetailTGrid_FetchCellStyle(object sender, FetchCellStyleEventArgs e)
{
    decimal sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= DetailTGrid.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        sum = Convert.ToDecimal(DetailTGrid[i, 4]) * Convert.ToDecimal(DetailTGrid[i, 6]);

        if (sum != Convert.ToDecimal(DetailTGrid[i, 9]))
        {
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }        
}
```

By default, **FetchCellStyle** will be disabled and will not be called. For FetchCellStyle to work, you must set the **FetchStyle** property for the desired **column** to **True**.

How to turn it on: http://helpcentral.componentone.com/docs/c1truedbgrid/disablingeditinginaspecifiedtruedbgridcell.htm

Comment: Hi, @Miko. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.